# What could be the integration approach for exchanging token with partner application using ping federate?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, pingfederate, federation

We have one app and we are doing authentication through ping federate using saml. We have a button in that application that opens up another partner web application that is hosted elsewhere. What we want is to exchange the logged in user information with our partner application that gets opened up on button.
What could be possible integration approaches for same using ping federate?

Comment: Is PingFederate acting as an SP only or an IdP as well? What is the integration mechanism between your app and PingFed?

Answer (score 1):

The fact of the user being signed in to your app buys you nothing with respect to your other (partner) app. The partner app would have to act as its own SAML service provider. When you click on the button, you would ask Ping to send a new SAML response to the partner app, thus signing the user in over there (SSO).

Comment: So, in this case on partner app user need not to login again, the partner app will send authn request to ping and against it ping will send a saml response. Is the ping instance need to be same on which my main app is connected, or I can have separate ping instance for partner app which will redirect request to main ping instance.

Comment: It needs to be the same instance